# Use or not to use the namespace::sweep and/or Modern::Perl

Tags: perl, moose

In my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22598331/632407) @Borodin commented my question with:

> You should start by removing Modern::Perl and namespace::sweep.
>   Modules that behave as pragma should be avoided.

I'm confused a bit, because:

- in the LATEST [Moose BestPractices manual](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.1204/lib/Moose/Manual/BestPractices.pod#namespace::autoclean_and_immutabilize) recommending to use `namespace::autoclean`.

> The use namespace::autoclean bit is simply good code hygiene, as it
>   removes imported symbols from your class's namespace at the end of
>   your package's compile cycle, including Moose keywords. Once the class
>   has been built, these keywords are not needed. (This is preferred to
>   placing no Moose at the end of your package).

In the Book `Intermediate perl` recommending to use the `namespace::autoclean` too.

Yes, I'm used the instead of the `autoclean` the `sweep` module - because again [from the doccu](http://search.cpan.org/~friedo/namespace-sweep-0.006/lib/namespace/sweep.pm)

> This pragma was written to address some problems with the excellent
>   namespace::autoclean. In particular, namespace::autoclean will remove
>   special symbols that are installed by overload, so you can't use
>   namespace::autoclean on objects that overload Perl operators.
>
> ...
>   ...
>
> In most cases, namespace::sweep should work as a drop-in replacement
>   for namespace::autoclean. Upon release, this pragma passes all of
>   namespace::autoclean's tests, in addition to its own.

And because I'm an perl beginner, i'm really confused. For me, when i reading: *this module addressing some problems of another module* - mean: *use this one*.

'Manual (where from I should learn) says "use it" and expert from stackoverflow teling: *don't use it*.

So please, can someone explain me:

- it is correct to use `namespace::sweep` or I should use `namespace::autoclean` or none of them?
- if none, why the BestPractices recommends it?

For the `ModernPerl'. Sure, I'm probably don't understand  deeply and "exactly" what is does. What i know, (again from it's doccu)

> This enables the strict and warnings pragmas, as well as all of the
>   features available in Perl 5.10. It also enables C3 method resolution
>   order as documented in perldoc mro and loads IO::File and IO::Handle
>   so that you may call methods on filehandles. In the future, it may
>   include additional core modules and pragmas.

Sure, don't deeply understand to `mro`, only think it is an answer to the "deadly diamond of death" problem in cases of multiple inheritance.

Up to today, i was really happy with it, because it is shorting for me the needed pragmas:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
```

So, what is a "status" of the "Modern::Perl" (and other similar cpanm modules)? Allowed to use, or not?

Comment: You've already got my answer since you cited my book. The advice that you should avoid modules that act as modules is a bit weird since pragmata are modules.

Comment: @briandfoy: What I said was *"Modules that behave as pragma should be avoided"*. I was referring to `Modern::Perl`, whose capitalisation implies that it adds functionality but makes no other change to the context of the following code. Its behaviour belies that. I am happy with `namespace::autoclean` where it is likely to help, but I believe that the boilerplate for the majority of simple Perl programs should be `use strict` and `use warnings`, and no more

Comment: @Borodin sorry, You said: _'remove namespace::sweep'_. I will cotinue to use `namespace::autoclean` or `namespace::sweep` - because it __is recommented__ (as a good code hygiene). Anyway, from now - i will not use the `Modern::Perl` - so, your comment teached me something new. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think Modern::Perl implies any of that. All sorts of non-pragma modules change the context of the following code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your question about namespace::sweep:

Firstly, take note of the actual problem that namespace::sweep resolves.

> In particular, namespace::autoclean will remove special symbols that are installed by overload, so you can't use namespace::autoclean on objects that overload Perl operators.

What this means is that if your class has overloaded operators they won't work if you also `use namespace::autoclean`. But this problem only occurs if you `use overload`. Other than that, namespace::autoclean will suffice.

Secondly, it says that namespace::sweep can be used instead of namespace::autoclean:

> In most cases, namespace::sweep should work as a drop-in replacement for namespace::autoclean. Upon release, this pragma passes all of namespace::autoclean's tests, in addition to its own.

So to answer your question, "is it correct to use namespace::sweep or I should use namespace::autoclean or none of them?"

1. You should use at least one of them as recommended by Moose Best Practices.
2. It is generally ok to use namespace::sweep since it says it is designed to do so and it passes all of namespace::autoclean's tests.
3. In spite of point 2 above, if you don't `use overload` then you don't have a problem with using namespace::autoclean, so you could just use that in this case.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I was used the `namespace::sweep` because _i was not sure_ about the `overload` (I'm still only learning perl). The merit of the original question is around the module "Path::Class" what _is_ overloading the "string" context. Probably it is safe to use `namespace::autoclean`.

Comment: `namespace::autoclean` only breaks overloading in the package it's imported into. Using it for your package won't break overloading in another package (`Path::Class`). Personally I prefer `namespace::sweep` over `namespace::autoclean` not just because of the overloading issue, but also because it works better for non-Moose classes. (FWIW, I prefer `Path::Tiny` over `Path::Class` too.)

Answer (score 3):

Specifying `use 5.014;` (or other version >= 5.011) will automatically do `use strict;` and enable all features of that version for you; IMO this is some of the reason Modern::Perl has not gained a whole lot of traction.

I've always disliked `Modern::Perl` because it doesn't describe what it does; it is someone else's idea of "modern" as of some fixed point in the past.

Comment: Modern::Perl has the oddity that you can't tell how much it is going to do if you don't know which version you have.

Comment: "Modern Perl", OTOH, the concept that we don't have to write perl the way we did a decade ago, I like very much.

Comment: Indeed, the idea and that particular module are different. Perl has the wart that we can't insist on a particular version, only that version or later (without tricky other modules and additional code, as I showed in Effective Perl Programming).