# how to replace a line after certain keyword in perl

Tags: shell, perl

#### rerun.txt

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,4
```

(`a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are `$var` and `1`, `2`... `$num` in my code)

I want to search for `$var` in `cell.txt` and replace `area` (its corresponding next line) by `$num` ( like `area : 1` ) in this file

#### cell.txt

```
  cell (a)  {
     area :  2
  }

  cell (b)  {
     area :  2.3
   }
  cell (c)  {
     area :  2.5
   }

  cell (d)  {
     area :  2.7
   }
```

#### Perl code

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open( my $fh1, "rerun.txt" ) or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";

my $word  = 0;
my $input = "area";
my $num;
my $var;
my $line;
my $a     = 0;
my $flag  = 0;
my $flag1 = 0;

while ( <$fh1> ) {

    ( $var, $num ) = split ",";    # splitting acc to comma

    open( my $fh, "cell.txt" ) or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";

    while ( my $line1 = <$fh> ) {    # while in the file opened

        $line1 =~ s/^\s+//;         # removing spaces
        my @word = split " ", $line1;    # splitting acc to spcaes

        foreach $word ( @word ) {

            $word =~ s/[(,),]//g;        # excluding all brackets (,),{,}

            if ( $word eq $var ) {
                $flag = 1;
            }

            if ( $flag == 1 ) {

                if ( $word eq "area" ) {

                    $a = $.;             # saving the line number
                    system( "sed -i '$a s/.*/\t area : $num /' cell.txt" );
                    goto L1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    L1:

    close( $fh );
}

close( $fh1 );
```

Comment: What does TCL have to do with it?

Comment: I've tidied your Perl code so that I can read it, but it's shameful that I need to do that at all. Please make a better effort next time you ask a question here.

Comment: Is every item in cell.txt going to be in rerun.txt?

Comment: @trenton-trama: there are few variables to be changed in cell.txt ,not all.

Answer (score 0):

I am relying on somewhat fancier regexes to try to be defensive about possible input and combine some steps. The [docs on `goto`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html) suggest [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) (in your case `last LABEL`) as an alternative but I hope the OP won't feel hurt by my echoing a dogma shared by some. My version prints to stdout instead of changing the original file but should be close enough.  Would have been helpful to print some expected output but hopefully I guessed right.

[Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) finished a few minutes before me and I did not see his posting which is in some ways a more advanced approach.  On suggestion from same I removed reference to `Regexp::Common` module which, while relevant, I agree was more than needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;

open(my $fh, '<', 'rerun.txt') or die "Could not open rerun.txt: $!";
my %new_area;
foreach (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($k, $v) = split ',';
    die "invalid rerun format" unless ($k =~ /^\w+$/ and $v =~ /^[\d.]+$/);
    $new_area{ $k } = $v;
}

open($fh, '<', 'cell.txt') or die "Could not open cell.txt: $!";
my $area_key;
while (<$fh>) {
    if ( /^\s* cell \s*\(\s*(\w+)\s*\)\s* { \s*$/x ) {
        $area_key = $1;
    }
    elsif (/^\s* } \s*$/x) {
        undef $area_key
    }
    elsif ( defined($area_key) and /\barea\b/ and
            exists $new_area{ $area_key }
    ) {
        s/(area\s*:\s*)[\d.]+/$1$new_area{$area_key}/
    }

    print;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
  cell (a)  {
     area :  1
  }

  cell (b)  {
     area :  2
   }
  cell (c)  {
     area :  3
   }

... etc ...
```

Comment: *"Your attempt looks to me a bit like a BASIC program written in Perl"* To be honest, that's how your answer looks to me. For a start, why no `use strict` or `use warnings 'all'`?

Comment: Borodin, it looks like you missed `use Modern::Perl;` - https://metacpan.org/pod/Modern::Perl

Comment: Why should I have to learn what every non-core compilation module does? It's opaque, and not a great example for newcomers. `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` is sufficient and self-explanatory. By all means use `Modern::Perl` for your own purposes, but it's not appropriate in production or public code.

Comment: And `Regexp::Common` is overkill. `[\d.]+` is fine unless you were trying to *validate* the input data, and if you were you would need to handle a mismatch  properly instead of just ignoring it. The OP doesn't imply that the files may be malformed, so there is no point in anything "clever".

Comment: I cannot understand the comment that Modern::Perl is not appropriate in production code http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_(programmer) - With regard to public code, I realize that I don't see it much on this site but am not quite sure why.

Comment: You need to add `@Borodin` for me to receive a notification of your message. I don't see the point of your link except to underline that Chromatic is a celebrity. Ask a number of Perl programmers what `use Modern::Perl` does and very few people will know the answer without looking at the documentation. Being non-core it needs to be installed to use it at all, and the result is a program with pragma that most people cannot define without help. I'll wager you don't know yourself what it does. It's a module that makes you look like you're trying too hard without caring about your audIence.

Comment: @Borodin - I knew that `Modern::Perl` included `use warnings;` and `use strict` which you missed in your initial comment.  I wish you would have checked before being so harshly critical.  You don't seem familiar with the module but I noticed positive reviews of the related book by several CPAN authors and am not sure the problem is so universal.

Comment: Did you even read my explanation? I would add that `Modern::Perl` doesn't look like a pragma, which conventionally have lower case names. If I overlooked it then doesn't it seem likely that others could do the same? I reflected your own criticism back to you, so presumably you think you were also being *"harshly critical"*? I would add that you should be using the three-parameter form of `open`, and you are unnecessarily checking for the existence of `area` in the line before doing the substitution. You don't appear to have a grasp of idiomatic Perl yet and shouldn't be throwing stones.

Comment: I may indeed have overreacted to the OP use of `goto`.  AFAICT I read all of your explanations.  The dispute about `Modern::Perl` has turned up  before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599829/use-or-not-to-use-the-namespacesweep-and-or-modernperl

Comment: Thanks @mr_ron i have very basic version of perl , and i cant instal modern::perl ,any solution for this.Thanks in advance

Comment: @Anthonyj - as described in other comments which also link to the doc for `Modern::Perl` (letter case matters), it could be replaced here with `use strict; use warnings;`.  Installing Perl/CPAN modules like `Modern::Perl` may greatly extend the power of Perl as a tool and seemingly can often be done without `root` or `admin` authority.  See https://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html for more.  I usually have root and admit to using `local::lib` installation today for the first time.

Comment: @mr_ron I was just trying cpan as I installed today , i want to change the parameter in cell.txt directly so i used open($fh, '>', 'cell.txt') instead of open($fh, '<', 'cell.txt') but im facing this error                                                  "Filehandle $fh opened only for output at new.pl line 7." Please help me out . Thanks in advance .

Comment: @Anthonyj you are very likely trying to read from a file you only have open for write.  Perl can open for read and write with `+<` and you could also consider `perl -i` edit in place ( http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html ).  My guess is it would be simpler to write a new file and move or copy files as a separate step.

Comment: @mr_ron Thanks for the help again.I have done perl change.pl | tee new_cell.txt as u have suggested.

Comment: @mr_ron Thanks for the help again.I have done perl change.pl | tee new_cell.txt as u have suggested.But if in my cell.txt i have area : "2" ; then I have to modify last line of ua code Please help me whether I should do like this  s/(area\s*:\s*)"[\d.|\w.]"+/$1$new_area{$area_key}/  ? but its not working (I have added \w. as if my rerun.txt contains a word )                                Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe: `s/(area\s*:\s*)"[\d.|\w.]+"/$1$new_area{$area_key}/` ... the `+` needs to be after the `]` not the `"`.

Answer (score -1):

This solution reads the *rerun* data into hash `%rerun`, using the first column for keys and the second for values. A regex pattern `$re` is built from the set of possible keys and compiled

The entirety of `cell.txt` is read into `$cell` to make it simpler to process multi-line strings. Each occurrence of `cell (x) {` with a following `area : 99.99` and where `x` is one of the keys of `%rerun` is found, and the subsequent `99.99` is replaced by the value of the corresponding hash element

Once everything has been found and replaced, the new `$cell` is printed to `STDOUT`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

my %rerun = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'rerun.txt';
    map { /[^,\s]/g } <$fh>;
};

my $cell = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'cell.txt';
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

my $re = join '|', sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %rerun;
$re = qr/$re/;

$cell =~ s/ \b cell \s* \( \s* ( $re ) \s* \) \s* \{ \s* area \s* : \s* \K [\d.]+ /$rerun{$1}/gx;

print $cell;
```

#### output

```
  cell (a)  {
     area :  1
  }

  cell (b)  {
     area :  2
   }
  cell (c)  {
     area :  3
   }

  cell (d)  {
     area :  4
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @ Borodin, As I have added above , I have basic version of perl and I'm getting error for this as                                             BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at cell_new.pl line 3.. Please can you suggest me any solution . And yes im just learning  perl.

Comment: @Anthonyj It looks like you might be using a quite old version of Perl that did not include autodie as a core module/pragma. `corelist autodie` shows perl 5.10.1 as being the first such release and you might check `perl -v` to see if your version is earlier.